# Is it permissible to make dua for non-Muslims?

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim, dua

Is it permissible to make *dua* for non-Muslims? If so, then please suggest one for me, because I am to give out a *dua* for them in front of the whole school to pass their exams.

Comment: well! the simple answer is no. There are references in the Holy Quran and Ahadees but i am not that expert to give you references here

Comment: depend on what kinds dua, dua for hidayah is allowed

Comment: @rahelshan What's not allowed is to make dua that asks for forgiveness after they died. See TheCodeGuru's answer for reference

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can make dua for non muslims, an example of this is when rasul allah [pbuh] made dua for Umar [ra] to become a muslim. as for an example to use , read a dua for the general guidance of someone.

Answer (score 3):

Al-Quran says

> Ask forgiveness for them, (O Muhammad), or do not ask forgiveness for them. If you should ask forgiveness for them seventy times never will Allah forgive them. That is because they disbelieved in Allah and His Messenger, and Allah does not guide the defiantly disobedient people. [9:80]

which gives an idea that it is upto Allah granting our duas on whatever we asks. Also, he is in no favor of 'defiantly disobedient people'. So it might be a waste.

But however I went through some conversations. One most informative answer I have found from Mawlana Saanwal ibn Muhammad, UK, Student Darul Iftaa where he quotes a line from Prophet PBUH

> “All created beings are Allah’s dependents, and the most beloved of people to Allah is the one who is good to His (Allah’s) dependents.” [Al-Mu’jam Al- Awsat Vol:5 Pg:356 Dār –al- Haramain]

So, as a conclusion he says,

> Shariah teaches us to be good to all people, however, it is an unfortunate reality that majority of the people do not believe in the Allah and the religion of Islam. The people who do believe are special and divinely guided. Because of this, there are some things that are specific privileges for Muslims only; Salaam and Dua of forgiveness after death are two such things.
>
> As mentioned above; we wish well for all human beings; which is why we are permitted to make Dua for the guidance, health and well being of non-Muslims. It is prohibited to make Duas’ of forgiveness for a non-Muslim after his death.

I hope your problem might come into you 'well being' of non-muslim.

According to my knowledge the only most acceptable dua on a non-muslim is asking a better guidance of Islam for them.

Comment: In [9:80] it referred to the non Muslims who rejected Islam and died like that.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a scholar but my  practicing Muslim heart tells me to even  pray for living non Muslim if he or she does good to their fellow human being ( Muslim)  that's our Muslim teaching. Our prophet PBUH tells us that a smile is a charity and that is for every human being Muslim and non muslin alike. Be good to our neighbors (no religion is mentioned in Hadith books).

If Muslim needs food, shelter and clothes and when those things are provided by a non Muslim to needy one- it would be un lslamic If good words of prayers don't come out of that muslim's heart for that particular  non Muslim " May Allah SWT give you AJR for your good deed" and of course words of "Thank you".
Allah SWT knows the best.

Answer (score 1):

AsalamoAlikom
As evidenced by the following ayat and the background to its revelation stated below, Muslims are not allowed to pray for seeking forgiveness for a disbeliver.

Abu Taalib, the paternal uncle of the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) died, and he instructed ‘Ali to bury him, but the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) did not attend his funeral or his burial, even though Abu Taalib’s support and defence of the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) was well known, and even though the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) felt a great deal of compassion and mercy towards him. Nothing stopped him from doing that except the fact that Abu Taalib died in a state of kufr. In fact the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “I shall certainly pray for forgiveness for you so long as I am not forbidden to do so.” Then the words were revealed (interpretation of the meaning):

> “It is not (proper) for the Prophet and those who believe to ask
>   Allaah’s forgiveness for the Mushrikoon, even though they be of kin,
>   after it has become clear to them that they are the dwellers of the
>   Fire (because they died in a state of disbelief)”

[al-Tawbah 9:113] and:

> “Verily, you (O Muhammad) guide not whom you like,”

[al-Qasas 28:56].

Comment: I think asking for forgiveness after death and before death is different, don't mix it.

Answer (score 0):

I was once a Kafir before I had finally reverted to Islam to become a Muslim for so many years by now. My Muslim mentor was praying hard for so many donkey years to beg God to help convert me to Islam.  Why not? We Muslims can pray to God to ask His forgiveness for the non-Muslims, so that they might be like me having a chance to convert to Islam in the end.  Only God knows best, neither you nor me.
You decide only if you are a patient human being with the same red blood and an understanding heart.  
When Prophet Muhammad(saw) was first recognised as the spiritual guide of Islam in his own hometown, the first batch of Muslim converts were all his closed family members and best friends and they all were praying so hard for years to ask God to forgive those enemies of Islam in Mecca despite they were terrible and stubborn transgressors at that time.

Finally, great majority of those transgressors became Muslims after so many wars occurred between them.
  We don't even need to fight our modern enemies these days to help pray for them hoping they might become Muslims one day in future, then why couldn't we do so as a charity for them instead (such noble act will be rewarded by God for sure I believe)? Unless you have a heart like a dead stone without any mercy, pray for them all for God's sake!

Answer (score 0):

Muslims are allow to give charity to non-Muslims. The best of charity are making supplication for other without them knowing it. So making supplication for non-Muslim is allowed. But this is only possible for living non-Muslim. The supplication should specific and not general. Meaning to say we make supplication for a living person by specifying the name;
For example,"my Lord,forgive my (non-Muslim) parents, grant Islam into their hearts".
 It should not be "my Lord,forgive the non-Muslim."
 the latter is an incorrect supplication,because such a general supplication is general,which include dead non-Muslim. Which is the same when we say Allah, forgive the Muslim. This supplication will be for every muslim,dead or living

Comment: Salaam and welcome to Islam.SE. You answer can improve by providing references for your statements.

Answer (score -3):

It is not prohibited for us to make dua for non muslims as the holy quran states: if a person desires any religion besides islam, it will never be accepted of him'.

Comment: Please consider to elaborate a good answer (see [answer]).

Answer (score -4):

You can't make dua for a kafir !! People who are saying you can are wrong you cant ! You can only make dua for their guidance to islam. You cant for health or forgivness after they die this is wrong 
The proof is the hadith when Muhammad SAW,

> It was narrated that Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “I asked my Lord for permission to pray for forgiveness for my mother, but He did not give me permission; I asked Him for permission to visit her grave, and He gave me permission.” [Narrated by Muslim, 976](https://sunnah.com/muslim/11/134)

This hadith is clear proof that you can NOT ask forgiveness for a non-Muslim at all. 
Your asking forgiveness for their shirk and them worshipping others besides Allah swt.. . 
.

> It was narrated from Anas ibn Maalik (may Allaah be pleased with him) that a man said: “O Messenger of Allaah, where is my father?” He said: “In the Fire.” When he turned away, he called him back and said: “My father and your father are in the Fire.” [Narrated by Muslim, 203](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/408).

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. For more information about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As to your post these both ahadith only allow to conclude a ruling for dead people! While the Qur'an says:"My Lord, indeed they have led astray many among the people. So whoever follows me - then he is of me; and whoever disobeys me - indeed, You are [yet] **Forgiving and Merciful**." ([14:36](https://legacy.quran.com/14/36)). Which is a du'a for living people and their off-spring!